# ABPeoplePicker delegate returns incorrect identifier when Exchange and iCloud phone numbers are in the same entry

Tags: ios, ios7, abaddressbook

I am having an issue where the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController seems to be returning the wrong identifier for contacts that have phone numbers synchronized from both Exchange and iCloud. My application is running on iOS 7.1 and is compiled with iOS 7.1 SDK.

TL;DR - In the people picker delegate callback I am getting the wrong identifier when I have a contact that has phone numbers from both Exchange and iCloud merged together.

Preemptive Answer: Yes I am calling ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier.

This problem only happens when I have a single contact with phone numbers from both Exchange and iCloud. I ran an older version of the application compiled with iOS 6.1 SDK and it does not have the problem when running under iOS 7.1.

I have simplified the test down to:

iPhone is registered to iCloud with Contact syncing enabled. The iPhone also is setup to check mail with Exchange. In Exchange. I have a contact called "Foo Bar" with three phone numbers and this contact displays in iPhone correctly. At this point everything is working as expected in my application:

- Work:     212-111-1111
- Mobile:   212-222-2222
- Home:     212-333-3333
- Work Fax: 212-444-4444

iPad is registered to iCloud with Contact syncing enabled. Email is not configured on this device. I created a user named "Foo Bar" with two phone numbers:

- Home Fax: 212-555-5555
- Work Fax: 212-666-6666

After the iCloud syncs the contacts I see that "Foo Bar" has 6 phone numbers in the iOS contacts app on the iPhone. Dialing from the iOS contacts app dials the correct number.

In my application I am displaying an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. In the delegate callback I am getting the wrong phone number.

In the people picker I see the contact with all 6 phone numbers in this order:

- Work: 212-111-1111
- Work Fax: 212-444-4444
- Home: 212-333-3333
- Mobile: 212-222-2222
- Home Fax: 212-555-5555
- Work Fax: 212-666-6666

In the delegate I am displaying all of the phone numbers and they always display in this order. It looks like the iCloud entries are in the list above the Exchange numbers (not that it should matter).

- xindex:0 phone:(212) 555-5555
- xindex:1 phone:(212) 666-6666
- xindex:2 phone:(212) 111-1111
- xindex:3 phone:(212) 444-4444
- xindex:4 phone:(212) 333-3333
- xindex:5 phone:(212) 222-2222

As I select each entry in the from the people picker I get these results in the people picker delegate:

- Work Phone: **identifier=0 index=0** phone=(212) 555-5555 (wrong:should be 212-111-1111)
- Work Fax:   **identifier=1 index=1** phone=(212) 666-6666 (wrong:should be 212-444-4444)
- Home:       **identifier=2 index=2** phone=(212) 111-1111 (wrong:should be 212-333-3333)
- Mobile:     **identifier=3 index=3** phone=(212) 444-4444 (wrong:should be 212-222-2222)
- Home Fax:   **identifier=0 index=0** phone=(212) 555-5555 (correct)
- Work Fax:   **identifier=1 index=1** phone=(212) 666-6666 (correct)

It looks like the identifier being passed to the delegate is not correct since 0 and 1 are used for 2 different entries. It could also be that the identifier to index mapping is also not correct.

Here is my simplified delegate callback:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
   shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
   property:(ABPropertyID)property
   identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty) {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
        if (multi != NULL) {
            //Display all the phone numbers for the object
            CFIndex xcount = ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);
            NSLog(@"xcount = %lu", (unsigned long)xcount);
            for (CFIndex xindex = 0 ; xindex < xcount ; ++xindex) {
                CFStringRef xphone = (CFStringRef)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, xindex);
                NSLog(@"xindex:%ld phone:%@", (long)xindex, (__bridge NSString*)xphone);
                if (xphone) { CFRelease(xphone); }
            }

            //Display the selected phone number
            CFIndex itemIndex = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multi, identifier);
            CFStringRef phone = (CFStringRef)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, itemIndex);
            NSLog(@"identifier:%ld itemIndex:%ld phone:%@", (long)identifier, (long)itemIndex, (__bridge NSString*)phone);

            if (phone) { CFRelease(phone); }
            CFRelease(multi);
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I would expect to see a different identifier for each phone number that would map to the correct index number. Is there a step I am missing? Is this a bug in iOS 7?

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier() (or the data behind it) is definitely broken in iOS 8 and 9. I can't tell for iOS 7 since we didn't had crash tracking back then. Example:

- Have a new contact with 2 addresses
- Identifiers are now (0, 1) and the corresponding indexes (0, 1) which is correct
- Delete the first address
- Identifier for the remaining address is (1) and the index (-1)

That the identifier remains 1 is understandable, as it is an identifier. But the index should be 0. What happens becomes more obvious when you use 3 addresses:

- (0, 1, 2) and (0, 1, 2)
- Delete first address
- Becomes (1, 2) and (1, -1)
- Clicking the first address returns the second one
- Clicking the second address results in a crash (if you don't check for index -1 which you actually should not have to in the first place)

ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier seems to return the identifier if the id exists as an index or -1 if the id exceeds the index range.

I tried to attack from a different angle but ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex seems broken, too. So iterating over the entries does not help either. ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex always seems to return the index itself (iOS 9).

So far I have to assume that this is a bug in iOS. If I use my test-contact in other apps they seem to have the exact same issue. Given your data it looks like the identifiers and the id-to-index-mapping really are broken. For me the ids were reasonable (at least).

I think reporting won't help since the ABPeoplePicker got discontinued with iOS 9.